# Parse gRPC orginal body with Tonic Prost

Tags: rust, grpc, rust-tokio, rust-tonic, prost

I have an original body of a gRPC request that I want to decode to a Protobuf Message using Prost (and probably Tonic).

As I see the HTTP body part consist of a `grpc-header` + `protobuf-message`. In my case the header is just 5 bytes like `000000003b`, which to my understanding are some gRPC flags (all zeroes) and length (`3b`) of the actual message. I receive just as bytes as part of other payload, it's not a http request by itself only its bytes, so don't have `Request` or other data provide by Tonic.

I looked at the Tonic's source code and I found some code to process it, but I'm not sure how I supposed to call it. My understanding that I should use `ProstCodec` and give a `DecodeBuf` as an input. But I don't see a way to create an instance of it. Its `::new` is crate-only and there is no `From`/`TryFrom`. So my guess it should not be used from an external code. And I cannot use `ProstCode` directly then.

So my question is how to process the original gRPC body and decode a message from it? Is there any wrapper around `ProstCodec` that I can use?